# Adding Default Variables to Zend2 ViewModel

Tags: php, zend-framework2, viewmodel

What's the "Zend" way of adding default variables to the ViewModel.

Currently I have:

```
return new ViewModel(array('form' => new CreateUserForm));
```

But I want to always add some variables to the ViewModel array.  Like the time and date say, or categories for a menu.  I was thinking of extending the ViewModel as that seems the OO way, but Zend always does things differently...

Comment: You would probably want to use a ViewHelper for stuff like rendering menus. Have a look here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always extend the ViewModel if you want some extra functionality in there...

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel
{
     /**
      * Default Variables to set
      */
     protected $_defaultValues = array(
        'test' => 'bob'
     );

     /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param  null|array|Traversable $variables
     * @param  array|Traversable $options
     */
    public function __construct($variables = null, $options = null)
    {
        //$variables = array_merge($this->_defaultValues, $variables);
        $this->setVariables($this->_defaultValues);

        parent::__construct($variables, $options)
    }
}
```

Now in your controller just use return your new view model instead:

```
/**
 * Some Controller Action 
 */
function myAction()
{
     return new MyViewModel();
}
```

Comment: This is the way I was thinking.  But is this the "Zend" way?

Comment: there's many ways to do things using ZF2 it doesn't force you use a certain way of developing, though this can be both good and bad :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to have a method in your controller that returns ViewModel populated with time, date, etc. and then addVariables() to the returned model in the Action.

However, a better approach will be to use **view helpers** since they will be available in every view/layout throughout the application.